# Selecting a form input with no name using Ruby Mechanize gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I am attempting to post events to websites from my database using the mechanize gem. The problem I am having is that many of the required inputs do not have a name available. I have tried various ways of selecting them via css, but each time they simply return nil. Here is my code:

```
require 'mechanize'
#navigate to sign in page
puts "Running....."
agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
agent.user_agent_alias = "Mac Safari"
}
page = agent.get('http://events.ctpost.com/home')
puts page.uri
link = page.link_with(text:'Add Event')
page = link.click
puts page.uri
#--------Enter sign in credentials----------

#enter email
form = page.forms.first

form['email'] = 'myemail'
#enter password
form = page.forms[1]
form['password'] = 'password'
page = form.submit
puts page.uri
pp page
#-------Create Event-------

#fill out event form
event_title = "House Show"
event_description = "House show at Joe's House"
event_venue = "Joes House"
event_date = "03/14/2018"
event_start_time = "7:00pm"

form = page.forms.first
form['title'] = event_title
form['description'] = event_description
form['price'] = "free"
form['phone'] = "666-666-6666"
form['event_venue'] = event_venue
```

and here is the element I am trying to select:

```
<input id="startTime" type="text" placeholder="* Start Time" class="required input-full time ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Is it possible to select this via the id or some other css attribute? I have never used mechanize before. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it doesn't have a name then it doesn't get sent. Only inputs with names get sent.

Comment: Thank you! That is good to know. But what if it is a required field? A lot of the fields I am running into with no names happen to be required.

Comment: Required doesn't mean anything in terms of what gets sent. If you want to send a custom name/value you just do `form['foo'] = 'bar'`

Comment: Alright, thanks for shedding some light on that for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
form.fields_with(:id => 'something').each do |field|
  field.value = 'hello!'
end
```